# Opening a class-generated PDF on the servlet to a new tab of a browser

Tags: java, pdf, servlets

Ok, so I have this dilemma where I wanted my web application to open a new tab with my newly created PDF. What did I do wrong here?

```
  PDFWriter pdf = new PDFWriter();
            pdf.setResId(resID);
            pdf.setEmpId(driverEmpID);
            pdf.setLocation(location);
            pdf.setReservationDetails(viewEach);
            pdf.setCarsModel(carsModel);
            pdf.execute(connection);
            File pdfFile = new File(location+resID+".pdf");

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename="+location+resID+".pdf");
            response.setContentLength((int) pdfFile.length());
            System.out.println("The file location is " + location+resID+".pdf");
            System.out.println("The size of the pdf file is " + (int) pdfFile.length());
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "cache, must-revalidate");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            response.sendRedirect("administrator");
```

In case of you were wondering what the String location was, it's this, except it's double slashed:

> K:\iACADEMY\3rd year 2nd sem\Thesis1\ws\iDriveTheThird\pdf\Trip-TicketReservation#

Basically, I use PDFWriter to create the PDF for me and store it on the directory that String location specified, with resId as a number in to prevent multiple instances of the same file name.
After the user has finished inputting the data on the form, it should open the generated PDF on a new tab.

Question is, what did I do wrong here?

Comment: What exactly has [tag:itext] to do with this? I don't see anything iText specific, neither in code nor in prosa.

Comment: I typed the itext code on the PDFWriter class.

Comment: If you think the issue might be due to your itext related code, show that code. If you don't think so, don't tag your question as itext related.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification.